# How to make bullet follow mouse

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game for a project but I was not taught nearly enough to make even a simple game so even though there are similar questions here, I am unsure of how to alter it to fit my game.

I did manage to make bullets but it only shoots upwards whereas I need it to shoot at wherever the mouse is.

I tried to follow some of the answers here but it will come up with error messages and if I try to edit those, even more error messages pop up and I really don't know why.

This is what I have so far:

```
Code is removed for now. Will re-upload in 1 to 2 months.
```

```
run = True

while run:

   [...]

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet = Bullet()
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
            all_sprite_list.add(bullet)
```

and this is my entire code if it helps:

```
Code is removed for now. Will re-upload in 1 to 2 months.
```

I am painfully aware that this game is highly flawed and I would appreciate any help I can get, even if it is not related to this question. (For example, collision detection of bullet and enemy. Collision detection of player and enemy) But for now, this problem is my biggest concern. Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your mouse position in event pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    aim_pos = event.pos
```

You may also want the bullet to follow the direction where you shoot.

```
player_position = player.rect.center

# Assume you have got where you're aiming by aim_pos.
bullet_vec = pygame.math.Vector2(aim_pos[0] - player_position[0],
                                 aim_pos[1] - player_position[1]).normalize() * 10 #move speed
bullet = Bullet()
bullet.rect.center = player.rect.center
bullet.vec = bullet_vec
all_sprite_list.add(bullet)
```

And moves following the direction.

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ....your codes

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.vec.x, self.vec.y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really works. May I ask how I can stop the bullet from passing through the walls?

Comment: @ignorant_idiot you can use `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(bullet, wall_list)`, or passing `walls` like what you did in `Enemy` and `Player`

Comment: By the way, you can also use self.kill() in Bullet.update, which will remove the bullet from **all** sprite groups.

Comment: I used `if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(bullet, wall_list): self.kill()` which kind of works but if I shoot multiple bullets at once, only one will hit the wall and the rest will pass through.

Comment: @ignorant_idiot where did you put your `self.kill()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def update(self):
    self.rect.y -= 3
```

This is the part of the code that controls the feature you asked about (where the ball moves), but I guess you know that because you wrote it.

> it will come up with error messages and if I try to edit those, even more error messages pop up and I really don't know why.

Well, that's programming for you. Keep fixing them.

I would strongly recommend installing a linter, by the way. Running `pylint` on your code gives me all this, which seems like the kind of feedback you are asking us for:

```
$ pylint --errors-only your-game.py
************* Module game
your-game.py:8:0: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member (no-member)
your-game.py:30:21: E1121: Too many positional arguments for lambda call (too-many-function-args)
your-game.py:45:21: E1121: Too many positional arguments for lambda call (too-many-function-args)
your-game.py:93:21: E1121: Too many positional arguments for lambda call (too-many-function-args)
your-game.py:130:21: E1121: Too many positional arguments for lambda call (too-many-function-args)
your-game.py:299:25: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member (no-member)
your-game.py:301:25: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'MOUSEBUTTONDOWN' member (no-member)
your-game.py:336:25: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member (no-member)
your-game.py:339:27: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'KEYDOWN' member (no-member)
your-game.py:340:28: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'K_LEFT' member (no-member)
your-game.py:342:30: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'K_RIGHT' member (no-member)
your-game.py:344:30: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'K_UP' member (no-member)
your-game.py:346:30: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'K_DOWN' member (no-member)
your-game.py:349:27: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'KEYUP' member (no-member)
your-game.py:350:28: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'K_LEFT' member (no-member)
your-game.py:352:30: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'K_RIGHT' member (no-member)
your-game.py:354:30: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'K_UP' member (no-member)
your-game.py:356:30: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'K_DOWN' member (no-member)
your-game.py:359:27: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'MOUSEBUTTONDOWN' member (no-member)
your-game.py:376:0: E1101: Module 'pygame' has no 'quit' member (no-member)
```

Also, let's talk about this:

```
wall = Wall(0, 0, 10, 800)                                                    
wall_list.add(wall)                                                           
all_sprite_list.add(wall)
```

For hundreds and hundreds of lines. You could just program the computer to generate all those positions for you. But even if you don't want to do that, Don't Repeat Yourself like this.

```
walls = (
         (0, 0, 10, 800),
         (40, 40, 10, 75),
         (50, 40, 190, 10),
         # ...
        )
for wall_coords in walls:
    wall = Wall(*wall_coords)
    wall_list.add(wall)
    all_sprite_list.add(wall)
```

That's 43 lines to your 144 doing exactly the same thing - a lot easier to read, and to edit, if you keep the sheer volume of your code under control.

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at it, when `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, you create a new Bullet() at the position of the player. Then, when you update the bullet. you shift its `y` coordinate up by 3 units.

I'd recommend giving each `bullet` a `velocity` and `target` attribute.
This will allow you to "fire and forget" each bullet, without having to worry about
manually updating it each time.

```py
def __init__(self, velocity: float, target: tuple or list):
    # other stuff
    self.velocity = velocity
    self.target = target

def update(self):

    # get the angle towards the target
    x_delta = self.target[0] - self.rect.x
    y_delta = self.target[1] - self.rect.y
    rotation = -math.atan2(y_delta, x_delta)

    # move towards the target
    self.rect.x += math.cos(rotation) * self.velocity
    self.rect.y -= math.sin(rotation) * self.velocity
```